# Selenium - How do you pull data from a .CSV File, using Python

Tags: python, csv, automation, automated-tests

We are currently new Python users, who have been tasked with working out to automate our test suites.

We currently are trying to do the following, although struggling to find how to pull data from a .CSV file.

The task is as follows:

1. Open an application
2. Select an item (based on the item name stored in a .csv file - This is what we are struggling
3. ... and so on.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. This site is good for more clear specific questions, rather than open-ended "design my app" posts. There's a built in `csv` module in python...

Comment: Would it be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+[csv]+read+file+ ?

Comment: It was not our intention to pose an open ended questions, from what olyv (thanks) we have been using the wrong terminology when searching, using pull rather than read. Thanks both of you